# Visual Studio 2010: Easiest way to duplicate a class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there an easy way to duplicate a class with a different name?

Comment: If you're planning on keeping the old class, I think your design is flawed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure whether this can be qualified as the easiest way but if you have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper), you can use its [Copy Type](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Copy_Type.html) refactoring to copy classes/interfaces/structs with control over the namespace the copy is landing in and naming within the copy - which means that if you're copying a class with 5 constructors, the copy will have all of them renamed to match the name of the new class.

However, depending on what you're trying to achieve, using [Extract Interface](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Extract_Interface.html) or [Extract Superclass](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Extract_Superclass.html) might be a better option.

Answer (score 6):

Refactor to give a new name, copy, undo, paste :-) Remember the undo! This will rename the constructors and finalizers!

Comment: Now that is the *real* answer for doing it just in Visual Studio. A pity that it has to be that difficult, but it's better than editing each occurrence of the class name manually.

Comment: With PowerTools 'Copy as Class' feature gone in VS 2022, this answer is relevant again and does the job.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no refactoring tool for duplicating a class but with different name.

I would imagine that the reason why this feature is not present is because duplicating code is generally considered a bad idea. I'd suggest instead changing your class into a base class and then make two derived classes from it, overriding methods where you need to change the behaviour.

Comment: It's almost certain they would then alter the class. The two derived classes you mentioned, for the most part one would be a copy of the other when you have the same properties but different values... so the same situation arises.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: now there is the option of "Copy Class" with the MS powertools for VS (marketplace)

Second: to all the critics that know better - there are legitimate cases where you want to copy a class as a starting point. I for example have a base class and from it I derive dozens of classes with different implementations, yet I do have a "reference class" derived from the base which already contains the overides, comments, etc. so I do not have to repeat the same over and over again.
This is just one of the many situation where you want to copy a class.

Comment: Agreed, there are legit cases. For example right now I have multiple derived classes from an abstract class. They all override the base properties with different values. So 90% of the source is the same between them, just the values. So copying and changing is the best option for that without engineering a whole new system. The cas for KISS applies here.

Comment: @JohnStock If 90% of the code in derived classes is the same, then why it is not implemented in the base class? You are doing it wrong.

Comment: @IgorLevicki there are many reasons why you cant put it in a base class, separate projects just being the most obvious, existing code bases that cant be modified, serialization issues, etc, etc.

Comment: @Hefaistos68 Sorry, but there is no legitimate reason to have 90% of code copy-pasted in several derived classes. Whoever is doing that should not be writing code because they are just leaving mess for someone to have to wade through and refactor later.

Answer (score 1):

- Open file in Visual Studio.
- Press `Ctrl+A`.
- Press `Ctrl+C`.
- Create a new file for the new class.
- Press `Ctrl+V` in the new file.
- Replace all old class names with the new one. (`Ctrl+H`)

Comment: precisely the opposite of what has been asked

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to refactor your class to be reusable. Copy paste code leads to having to fix the same code in multiple places and much pain as you're breaking OO principles.

Answer (score -1):

When developing the cloning is the best way to achive final refactoring still having working copy of the origin.

After developing you can just remove unnecessary objects.