# IntelliJ Idea F5 equivalent in Resharper

Tags: intellij-idea, resharper

In IntelliJ Idea when I use F5 keyboard I can copy the class using a new name. I wonder whether there is any equivalece in Resharper?

Comment: F5 is used to debug your code in Visual Studio. To copy a class, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008893/visual-studio-2010-easiest-way-to-duplicate-a-class